# Specifying the Kubernetes version in Docker Desktop for Mac

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

It looks like Docker Desktop for Mac is using a 1.22+ version of Kubernetes which introduces a number of breaking changes specifically to the `ingress-nginx` controller `apiVersion`. This is causing issues with our local development cluster.

There are couple options:

1. Rolling back the Kubernetes version to something `<1.22` in the development cluster.
2. Updating `ingress-nginx` and the development configuration to use `>=1.22`.

I'm trying to go with route `1.` and downgrade the version to match our production cluster: `v1.20.7` primarily because 1.22+ isn't available in Azure yet it looks like. It makes sense to me to have the development and production versions match.

That is my question: **How do you change the version of Kuberentes that `docker-desktop` uses?**

If that can't be done, then I guess I'll just have to go with `2.`

---

What've tried so far is simply following the `kubectl` [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-macos/):

```
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/v1.20.7/bin/darwin/arm64/kubectl"

chmod +x ./kubectl

sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

kubectl version --client
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.0", GitCommit:"ab69524f795c42094a6630298ff53f3c3ebab7f4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-12-07T18:08:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/arm64"}
```

Skeptical it was going to work and sure enough it doesn't.

---

Edit:

Option **3.**: use something like `minikube`, `microk8s`, `k3d`, etc.

It is looking like the only way to downgrade change the `kubectl` version is to downgrade Docker Desktop for Mac.

Comment: (This was one of a couple of reasons I stopped using the Docker Desktop Kubernetes integration; I'm currently using Minikube.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As best as I could determine, there is not a way to do this. (Please correct me if I'm wrong).

The options appear to just be:

1. Downgrade Docker Desktop for Mac to a version that has the version of Kubernetes that you want. Can find previous versions here: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/release-notes/
2. Use something like `minikube`, `mikrok8s`, `k3d`, etc. that gives you better control over the Kubernetes version being used.

I ended up just dong `1.` as opposed to adding another tool to our development environment, but `2.` feels like a much better option.